# how to acess the textblock in list

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

1. I have a TextBlock in the list which
2. I need to change the style
   of text
3. I need to change the background colour of the TextBlock

My problem is I can't change both text and image if anyone knows about this, please help me to solve this problem.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock  x:Name="student" text="default"
                        FontSize="14"
                        FontWeight="SemiBold"
                        Foreground="blue"
            </TextBlock>
            
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use  [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper?view=winrt-22621) to find the child.

**Xaml:**

```
 <ListView  x:Name="MyListView" SelectionChanged="MyListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock 
                        x:Name="student"      
                        Text="default"
                        FontSize="14"
                        FontWeight="SemiBold"
                        Foreground="blue"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
  private void MyListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get selected listviewitem
        ListViewItem item = MyListView.ContainerFromItem(MyListView.SelectedItem) as ListViewItem;
        // the DependencyObject is the TextBlock that you want to get
        DependencyObject targetelement = FindChild(item, "student");

        TextBlock selectedText = targetelement as TextBlock;
        selectedText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        if (e.RemovedItems.Count>0) 
        {
            // change unselected item color 
            ListViewItem removedItem = MyListView.ContainerFromItem(e.RemovedItems.FirstOrDefault()) as ListViewItem;
            DependencyObject removedelement = FindChild(removedItem, "student");

            TextBlock removedText = removedelement as TextBlock;
            removedText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        }
    }

    public DependencyObject FindChild(DependencyObject parant,string name)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
            if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == name)
                return MyChild;

            var FindResult = FindChild(MyChild, name);
            if (FindResult != null)
                return FindResult;
        }
        return null;
    }
```